# Fix overlap Decision Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

Can please help me in fixing the overlap in the decision tree.
Can you suggest a better code?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzset{
treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
 grow                    = right,
 sibling distance        = 8em,
 level distance          = 8em,
 edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
 every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
 sloped
]
\node [root] {Venture to start}
child { node [env] {Restaurant}
child { node [env] {-\$30}
    edge from parent node [below] {50\% Fail} }
child { node [env] {\$sssss100}
    edge from parent node [above, align=center] {50\% success}}
edge from parent node [above] {} }          
child { node [env] {Coffee Shop}
child { node [env] {-\$30}
    edge from parent node [below] {50\% Fail} }
child { node [env] {\$00}
    edge from parent node [above, align=center]
    {50\% success}
    node [below] {}}
edge from parent node [above] {} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust single nodes locally by adding `yshift=...` to the options, like

```
node [env,yshift=15] {-\$30}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzset{
treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
 grow                    = right,
 sibling distance        = 8em,
 level distance          = 8em,
 edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
 every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
 sloped
]
\node [root] {Venture to start}
child { node [env] {Restaurant}
child { node [env] {-\$30}
    edge from parent node [below] {50\% Fail} }
child { node [env,yshift=-15] {\$100}
    edge from parent node [above, align=center] {50\% success}}
edge from parent node [above] {} }          
child { node [env] {Coffee Shop}
child { node [env,yshift=15] {-\$30}
    edge from parent node [below] {50\% Fail} }
child { node [env] {\$00}
    edge from parent node [above, align=center]
    {50\% success}
    node [below] {}}
edge from parent node [above] {} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```